# How get property value if property class C# use reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have two classes

```
public class A
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class B
{
   public A A {get; set;}
}
```

How I can get value of Name from object B property of A?

Now I use

```
        string fromName = GetPropertyName(from);
        string toName = GetPropertyName(to);

        PropertyInfo oldProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(toName);
        PropertyInfo newProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(fromName);

        var oldValue = newProperty.GetValue(item);

        if (cryptVal != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oldValue.ToString()))
        {
            string newVal = provider.get(oldValue.ToString());

            property.SetValue(item, newVal, null);
        }

        private static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T,object>> property)
        {
            var memberNames = new List<string>();

            var memberExpression = property.Body as MemberExpression;

            while (null != memberExpression)
            {
                memberNames.Add(memberExpression.Member.Name);
                memberExpression = memberExpression.Expression as MemberExpression;
            }

            memberNames.Reverse();

            return string.Join(".", memberNames.ToArray());
        }
```

But get value by name Device.Name impossible :). Here I think need check if property name have dot, need use Split and get value object class and then get property. But maybe there are other variants?

Comment: Why do you need to do that with reflection versus just `bInsatnce.A.Name`?

Comment: @Derek's answer answers the question as it's currently formulated, but Selman22 notes that you tagged this with "reflection."  What do you need reflection for?  Do you not actually know the names of all the classes and properties?  If so, please edit your question to reflect what you *don't* know.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var b = new B();

 b.A = new A()
 {
    Name = "Hello World"
 };

 Console.WriteLine(b.A.Name);
```